# How to export a schedule to Google Calendar?

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

I'm writing an app in Django, I would like to be able to allow users to export an event schedule to Google Calendar.

I was thinking about exporting the schedule to an iCal file, but I would have to use some unpopular third party libraries, which sounds like a lot of trouble. Does Django have a functionality like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export it as CSV, much easier, and Google calendar supports it as Import format